# How to identify a wildcard date

Tags: vba, date, outlook

When an email from a specific sender with a specific subject comes in, my VBA code will do things with the attachment. An example of the subject line is:

```
Profit and Loss Summary 06-20-2014
```

Here is the code I have adapted from  http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/outlook-vba/automate-outlook/

```
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim TwoDays As Variant
  Set Msg = Item
  If (Msg.SenderName = "My Fav Sender") And _
   (Msg.Subject = "Profit and Loss Summary"& " " & Format(Date, "MM_DD_YYYY")) And _
   (Msg.Attachments.Count = 1) Then
```

This recognizes today's date. I need the code to identify any date (because sometimes the reports can come in a few days later than usual, but I still want the macro to run).

How do I use a wildcard date to this end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not ignore the date, since you don't care what it is, and just look for the string `"Profit and Loss Summary "` at the beginning of the subject?

```
InStr(Msg.Subject, "Profit and Loss Summary ") = 1
```

as in

```
If Msg.SenderName = "My Fav Sender" And _
    InStr(Msg.Subject, "Profit and Loss Summary ") = 1 And _
    Msg.Attachments.Count = 1 Then
```

Note that this will filter out replies like `Re: Profit and Loss Summary 06_20_2014`. If you don't want this, then consider instead:

```
InStr(Msg.Subject, "Profit and Loss Summary ") <> 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've decided to adapt your code!

Answer (score 1):

The `Like` operator in VB/VBA can allow easy use of wildcard string comparisons.

Change the line

`(Msg.Subject = "Profit and Loss Summary"& " " & Format(Date, "MM_DD_YYYY")) And _`

to be

`(Msg.Subject Like "Profit and Loss Summary ##_##_20##") And _`

This will run the rest of the code for any email that is "Profit and Loss Summary " followed by a any pattern of digits that matches the #'s (this will allow all relevant dates through, but also some number like 99_99_2099 - a more robust approach would require changing the structure of your If statements, testing a date conversion of an extracted substring and so on, and it seemed to me you preferred the most simple but adequate approach).

Comment: *"ensure that it does have a date"* Well, it will let 98_76_2543 through.  But I guess it's safe to assume that this won't be a problem.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett yes, you are right - duly changed the description. I think in this case an alternative such as testing an extracted substring for a valid conversion to a date is probably beyond the OP's needs as you say.

Comment: Thanks so much @Cor_Blimey, the Like operator works well in my situation!